# Error when finding by foreign key on Typeorm

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I'm getting this error when I use the find method on a foreign key field on Typeorm. The thing is, this code is working, I get a correct result from the find method, but I get an editor error and wanted to know why and if there is a correct way to do.

If I try to use a string as value for the team key, I get this other error
[image]

I'm using typescript, node, typeorm and postgres.

This is my code. It's working even with the error.

[image]

This is the error I'm getting when I hover on the underlined text.
[image]

And this is my User entity

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Tried reloading your editor yet?

Comment: Yes, still getting the same error.